# Java Array with generic types in a class

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I know Java is particularly weird with Generic arrays, but I ran into a new problem with this:

If we want to create an array with generic type `T`, we could do something like:

```java
T[] arr = (T[]) new Object[size];
```

But I have a class, A, that itself accepts generic parameters

```java
class A<T1, T2> {}
```

and another class that accepts its own generic parameters:

```java
class B<U1, U2> {}
```

Inside the `B` class, I am trying to create an array of type `A<U1, U2>[]`. So my code looks like:

```java
A<U1, U2>[] arr = (A<U1, U2>[]) new Object[size];
```

But this isn't working. It is actually causing a runtime exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [A; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [A; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Is there a fix?

Comment: Yes, you simply keep the `Object[]` as-is (without the cast to T[]), as you'll have to cast at the site that you access the elements of the array anyhow (where those generic types likely reside). Basically, your class should encapsulate all of the mucking with generified arrays. Realistically, you'd be better off using a collection instead of an array, which already does this for you (e.g. `ArrayList`). For a more concrete answer, provide a more concrete example (e.g what you're actually doing).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is impossible. There is a simple fix though. Simply use a `List<A<U1, U2>>`, this is better in all ways, and works great.

---

If you need to hear why what you want simply cannot be done *and* is a bad idea even if somehow you could, let me try to expand:

> If we want to create an array with generic type T, we could do something like:

This is incorrect. You're not creating a new array with generic type T. That is not possible. You're creating a new array with component type Object, and then using an uglycast to assign it to a variable of type T[] which is a lie: You've merely convinced the compiler to abolish its usual type checking and treat an array that isn't `T[]`, as if it was, when it isn't. This **will** cause problems down the road.

Trivial example:

```
class Test {
  static String[] makeRealStringArray() {
    return new String[10];
  }

  static <T> T[] makeFakeStringArray() {
    return (T[]) new Object[10];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] x = makeFakeStringArray();
    x[5] = 10; // assign integer
    x = makeRealStringArray();
    x[5] = 20;
  }
}
```

This gets you an ArrayStoreException **on the last line** - the fake string array method managed to produce an array that doesn't do this. Also, trivially, `x.getClass().getComponentType()` returns `Object.class` for the fake string array and `String.class` for the real one.

Hence, it is simply incorrect to say that you 'made' an array of type T there. You didn't. You've managed to convince the compiler to *treat* an array of component type Object as if it was a String array when it isn't.

> I am trying to create an array of type A<U1, U2>[]. So my code looks like:

And as you found out, that's one of the limitations.

**You can't do what you want to do**. arrays are primitive, obsolete constructs you shouldn't be using. There is an exception, for now, for primitive component types (`byte[]` - you can use those). There is no benefit to them here. Use, instead, a `List<A<U1, U2>>` which works just fine.

In the end, generics are figments of the compilers imagination (they aren't reified - an instance of, say, a `j.u.List` simply does not know which component type it was created with), but have a sound typing system (you can't make impossible assignments without the compiler warnings you about it).

Arrays, in contrast, are reified - an array knows what its component type is, but its type system is unsound. You can get runtime-only ArrayStoreExceptions with no warnings.

Said somewhat differently, generics is entirely `javac` managing your types for you, and arrays are mostly ignored by javac and instead are 'protected' by `java` - the VM. These concepts are incompatible, so, **generics and arrays do not mix**. "But, I want to mix them!" - no, you don't, and, even if you somehow do, that is immaterial, because you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `(T[]) new Object[size]` doesn't throw an exception is that, probably, you are doing this in a generic context where the type variable `T` is unbounded, so its erasure is `Object`. So after type erasure, you are casting an object whose real runtime class is `Object[]`, to `Object[]`, which obviously does not fail.

The reason why `(A<U1, U2>[]) new Object[size]` throws an exception is that the erasure of `A<U1, U2>` is `A`, so after type erasure, you are casting an object whose real runtime class is `Object[]`, to `A[]`, which fails because `Object[]` is not a subclass of `A[]`.

If you had instead created the array with a type that is the erasure of the type you are casting it to, like the following, it won't throw an exception:

```
A<U1, U2>[] arr = (A<U1, U2>[]) new A[size];
```

or

```
A<U1, U2>[] arr = new A[size];
```

(Of course, there are other things you need to be careful about with arrays of generic types. That's why you get an unchecked warning.)